# Known upper bound for product of numbers?

Tags: analysis, number-theory

Is there a known method for computing the upper bound (in terms of $m$) for the product of some given numbers, $r, s, t, m... \in \mathcal{N} \cup \left\{0\right\}$ when $r + s + t \cdots \leq m$?

So what I would like to know is the tightest upper bound for $rst\cdots$.

Edit: I know there exists a trivial bound upper bound of $m^n$ where $n$ is the number of elements in the sum term $r + s + t \cdots \leq m$. But I'm wondering if there's a better bound than that.

Comment: So you intend that we can have any (finite) number of factors $rst\ldots$, and we're only restricted by their sum.

(Also it's a little silly to include $0$ in $\mathbb N$ for these purposes)

Comment: @Meelo Yes exactly. Also, agreed, it's trivial to include $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are allowed to choose as many factors as we desire, then it is clear that we should only use $3$'s and as few $2$'s in the product as possible. Notice first that we only need to deal with $3$ and $2$ since any $n\geq 4$ can be replaced by the two terms $2\cdot (n-2)\geq n$. However, moreover, notice that $3$ instances of $2$ gives the product $2^{3}$ which is less than $3^{2}$, meaning that any three twos should be replaced by two threes. Thus, if $f(m)$ is the maximum product obtainable, then we get:
$$f(3k)=3^k$$
$$f(3k+1)=\frac{4}3\cdot 3^{k}$$
$$f(3k+2)=2\cdot 3^k$$

If we allow only products with exactly $n$ factors, then we can make a similar argument to establish that no two terms should differ by more than $2$ (as otherwise, moving them closer together would increase their product); therefore, every term in a maximal sum must be either $\lfloor \frac{m}n\rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac{m}n\rceil$, and the exact upper bound can be obtained by knowing this. A slightly weaker, but easy to state upper bound is that a product with $n$ factors cannot exceed
$$\left\lceil\frac{m}n\right\rceil^n$$

Comment: Just a point of interest, if you allow for any real number and any number of terms, the terms would tend to $e$.  Indeed, $e$ is a bit less than 3 and more than 2, so it agrees with the natural number case.  I remember running across this problem a few years back in a problem of the month contest.

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes sense; the maximum is clearly obtained by  a factor $x$ repeated $m/x$ times - and if we ignore that $m/x$ ought to be an integer (which is valid if $m$ is much larger than $x$, which it will be), the maximum of $x^{m/x}$ for $m>1$ lies at $x=e$.